# Mouse click and Drag Instead of Horizontal Scroll bar( To view full content of child Div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need Mouse click and Drag instead of Horizontal scroll bar.

[image: Reference image]
**When i click and drag the child div that should move on left/right respect to dragging direction.**

Any solution with css or jquery/JS

My code:

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  width: 1000px;
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use mouseDown and mouseUp event and change the X position of parent container.

Comment: Errors of typo, in `border`, 'i' missing for `solid` and `overflow` should be `hidden` instead of `hihdden`

Answer (score 74):

This can be done with plain javascript. Add mouse eventListeners to the element you want to drag, capture your starting point and calculate the scroll X position of your mouse movement. While dragging, apply this position to your child element:

```js
let mouseDown = false;
let startX, scrollLeft;
const slider = document.querySelector('.parent');

const startDragging = (e) => {
  mouseDown = true;
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
}

const stopDragging = (e) => {
  mouseDown = false;
}

const move = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(!mouseDown) { return; }
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const scroll = x - startX;
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - scroll;
}

// Add the event listeners
slider.addEventListener('mousemove', move, false);
slider.addEventListener('mousedown', startDragging, false);
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging, false);
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', stopDragging, false);
```

```css
.parent{
  width:300px;
  border:5px solid red;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
  float:left;
}
.child{
  width:1000px;
  float:left;
  font-size:15px;
  font-family:arial;
  padding:10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">    
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Suppose the child element contained a link, how would you disable the action on that element when dragging and only made it clickable when not drag was performed ?

Comment: @Catalin You can drag and also click any button/link inside the child div. I made a fiddle with Kurt's answer:  https://jsfiddle.net/5rvkum0p/2/

Comment: @Máster I think Catalin mentioned something else, the problem I have - when everything inside that container is clickable (image gallery, for example). I drag and move the child element, and it "clicks" the image below when releasing the drag.

Comment: Saved my night, thank you so much, worked with React and ref.current!

Comment: Works but seems to only move after you let go of the mouse or after several seconds. All of the functions run when you'd expect and all code runs without errors and logically as written. Any way to improve performance or any other possible cause of this?

Comment: If (while dragging) the *pointer* exits the target element it breaks. You should assign `pointermove` and `pointerup` events on `window` instead for a better UX.

Comment: Works also for touch events if the same eventlisteners are added for touchdown, touchup,touchmove, touchcancel. This does requires (two times) the e.pageX to be replaced by e.changedTouches[0].pageX (assuming only one touch position)

Comment: A similar solve can be used to create a vertical scrolling mechanism. For these use the properties `scrollTop` and  `offsetTop` instead of `scrollLeft` and `offsetLeft`, and `pageY` isntead of `pageX`

Answer (score 22):

You can use **.draggable()** function from jquery UI. Here's a link to sample i created based on your code. **Updated Code** http://jsfiddle.net/3mh2b7rk/4/

```js
jQuery("#child").draggable({ 
    cursor: "move", 
    containment: "parent",
    stop: function() {
      if(jQuery("#child").position().left < 1)
          jQuery("#child").css("left", "720px");
    }
});
```

```css
.parent{width:300px; border:5px solid red; overflow:hidden; left:20px}
.child-container{width:1730px;left:-710px;position:relative;}
#child{ width:1000px; float:left; font-size:15px; font-family:arial; padding:10px 5px 10px 0;left:720px; border-right:4px solid red}
.clear {clear:both;}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-container">
    <div id="child"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for good work, but here i want to revert a child div to original place when ".ui-draggable" left value going above "0". **I don't want to move the child div left to right when it's in original position.**

Comment: You can do that by adding the property revert: true in the draggable call. like jQuery( ".child" ).draggable({ cursor: "move", revert: true});

Comment: yes that's i want when left value changing to above "0". can you share any demo.    stop: function (event, ui) {
         var stop = ui.position.left;
         if (stop > 0 ) {
            ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true); 
         }
   else{
      $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
    }
     }

Comment: i have updated the demo code and updated my original comment.. http://jsfiddle.net/3mh2b7rk/1/

Comment: see i don't want to revert always , it's only need when child div left value css change to above 0, if value going in negative i don't want revert because am seeing the hidden content at that time.

Comment: that was slightly more complicated. I have updated the code. Hope this works for you. http://jsfiddle.net/3mh2b7rk/4/

Comment: For the benefit of searchers, this works for me. http://qnimate.com/javascript-scroll-by-dragging/

Answer (score 8):

### Simple drag scroll

Late to the party, but here's a simpler solution (for desktop and mobile devices) that uses Pointer events, `Event.movementX`, properly assigning events on `window` and the scrollable element, and CSS `touch-action: none;`

```js
const pointerScroll = (elem) => {

  let isDrag = false;
  
  const dragStart = () => isDrag = true;
  const dragEnd = () => isDrag = false;
  const drag = (ev) => isDrag && (elem.scrollLeft -= ev.movementX);
  
  elem.addEventListener("pointerdown", dragStart);
  addEventListener("pointerup", dragEnd);
  addEventListener("pointermove", drag);
};

document.querySelectorAll(".parent").forEach(pointerScroll);
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  touch-action: none; /* Add also this */
}

.child {
  width: 1000px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <b>Click, hold and move pointer</b>. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the case both vertical & horizontal scrolled is needed, change `const drag = (ev) => isDrag && (elem.scrollLeft -= ev.movementX);` to `const drag = (ev) => isDrag && (elem.scrollLeft -= ev.movementX) && (elem.scrollTop -=ev.movementY);` and set a fixed (max-)height to the parent

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to other answers because it made me confused for a long time:

Make sure you don't have [`scroll-behavior: smooth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) set in your styles, as that will ruin the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

I want to extend a little answer because few people had the same question about preventing the default behavior of child elements when dragged.

The basis of the code is not mine - I just added another event listener inside the first function because I had the same issue as people commenting that when dragging elements like an anchor with images they were fired after releasing a mouse button.

```
function clickAndDrag(selector, scroll_speed = 3, classOnEvent = 'grabbed_elem') {
    const slider = document.querySelector(selector);
    let isDown = false;
    let startX;
    let scrollLeft;

    slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        isDown = true;
        slider.classList.add(classOnEvent);
        startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
        scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
    
        // prevent default child behavior
        document.body.addEventListener('click', function( event ){
            if (slider.contains(event.target)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
    slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        isDown = false;
        slider.classList.remove(classOnEvent);
    });
    slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
        isDown = false;
        slider.classList.remove(classOnEvent);
    });
    slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
        if(!isDown) return;
        e.preventDefault();
        const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
        const walk = (x - startX) * scroll_speed; //scroll-fast
        slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
    });
}

// usage
clickAndDrag('.yourSelector');
```