# Angular Mouse Click and Drag Scroll in Horizontal

Tags: angular, typescript, scroll, mouseevent, drag

I am implementing a drag-on scroll feature in angular by referring to this [Mouse click and Drag Instead of Horizontal Scroll bar( To view full content of child Div)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576636/mouse-click-and-drag-instead-of-horizontal-scroll-bar-to-view-full-content-of-c) StackOverflow answer. But I am getting Cannot read property 'offsetLeft' of null error. I had linked my stackblitz code [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9mnvct?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

My HTML Code:

```
<div class="parent"  (mousedown) ="startDragging($event, false)" (mouseup) ="stopDragging($event, false)" (mouseleave) ="stopDragging($event, false)" (mousemove)="moveEvent($event)">
<div class="child">    
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum        
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS Code

```
.parent{
  width:300px;
  border:5px solid red;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
  float:left;
}
.child{
  width:1000px;
  float:left;
  font-size:15px;
  font-family:arial;
  padding:10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

My TS Code:

```
export class AppComponent {

  mouseDown = false;

  startX: any;

  scrollLeft: any;

  slider = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.parent');

  startDragging(e, flag) {
    console.log(e);
    this.mouseDown = false;
    this.startX = e.pageX - this.slider.offsetLeft;
    this.scrollLeft = this.slider.scrollLeft;
  }
  stopDragging(e, flag) {
    this.mouseDown = false;
  }
  moveEvent(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.mouseDown) {
      return;
    }
    const x = e.pageX - this.slider.offsetLeft;
    const scroll = x - this.startX;
    this.slider.scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft - scroll;
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me find the solution for it and share your knowledge as I am new to angular?

Comment: make your element draggable.

Comment: Your example had a lot errors. I fixed it up: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-phegzo?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I have created a directive exactly for doing this. https://github.com/azerafati/scroll-drag

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because `querySelector` on angular returns a null object to you variable, due to the DOM is not yet loaded when your component is built.

But there's two ways you can manage this:

1. Using `@ViewChild` decorator.

HTML Code:

```
<div #parent class="parent"  (mousedown) ="startDragging($event, false)" (mouseup) ="stopDragging($event, false)" (mouseleave) ="stopDragging($event, false)" (mousemove)="moveEvent($event)">
<div class="child">    
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum        
</div>
</div>
```

TS Code:

```
export class AppComponent {

  mouseDown = false;

  startX: any;

  scrollLeft: any;

  @ViewChild('parent') slider: ElementRef;

  startDragging(e, flag) {
    console.log(e);
    this.mouseDown = false;
    this.startX = e.pageX - this.slider.nativeElement.offsetLeft;
    this.scrollLeft = this.slider.nativeElement.scrollLeft;
  }
  stopDragging(e, flag) {
    this.mouseDown = false;
  }
  moveEvent(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.mouseDown) {
      return;
    }
    const x = e.pageX - this.slider.nativeElement.offsetLeft;
    const scroll = x - this.startX;
    this.slider.nativeElement.scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft - scroll;
  }
}
```

2. Passing the `parent` element to the functions:

HTML Code

```
<div #parent class="parent"  (mousedown) ="startDragging($event, false, parent)" (mouseup) ="stopDragging($event, false)" (mouseleave) ="stopDragging($event, false)" (mousemove)="moveEvent($event)">
<div class="child">    
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum        
</div>
</div>
```

TS Code:

```
export class AppComponent {

  mouseDown = false;

  startX: any;

  scrollLeft: any

  @ViewChild('parent') slider: ElementRef;

  startDragging(e, flag, slider) {
    console.log(e);
    this.mouseDown = false;
    this.startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
    this.scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
  }
  stopDragging(e, flag) {
    this.mouseDown = false;
  }
  moveEvent(e, slider) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.mouseDown) {
      return;
    }
    const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
    const scroll = x - this.startX;
    slider.scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft - scroll;
  }
}
```

Either ways achieve the expected behavior.

Comment: this example will only work, if you set the mouseDown Boolean to true in the startDragging method